# How to pass along cell value to row databound event after rowediting event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Below is my code behind:

```
public void enableEditMedChange(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    MedChangeTable.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
}

protected void MedChangeTable_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    using (DeveloprodDataClassDataContext adminDB = new DeveloprodDataClassDataContext())
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                DropDownList newMedChangeChangeDD = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("NewMedChangeChangeDD");
                newMedChangeChangeDD.SelectedValue = ???
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to set the drop down's selected value to whatever value was in one of the cells in the row who's edit button was clicked on. How can I pass along this value to the row data bound event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value like this:

```
DropDownList newMedChangeChangeDD = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("NewMedChangeChangeDD");
newMedChangeChangeDD.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "YourDataFieldName").ToString();
```

More informations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).